# Import pfx file with sn.exe using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, pfx

I am trying to install pfx file automatically every time the Azure Pipeline runs. Below is the powershell script i am trying to implement. I need it to provide the password automatically:

```
Set-Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools"

Start-Process -FilePath "sn.exe" -ArgumentList "-d",$container

Start-Sleep 2

Start-Process -FilePath ".\sn.exe" -ArgumentList "-i","c:\cert_2013.pfx",$container -NoNewWindow

Start-Sleep 2

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$($CerPass){ENTER}")

Start-Sleep 2

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

When the pipeline runs the ps1 file it is erroring out at `SendWait("$($CerPass){ENTER}")` Step. Below is the exact error message:

> Enter the password for the PKCS#12 key file:
>
> Could not read password for PKCS#12 blob in c:\cert_2013.pfx --
>   Console input may not be redirected for password entry.
>
> Exception calling "SendWait" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + & 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoLogo ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Exception calli...cess is denied":String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> At C:\PowerShellScript\CertReInstall.ps1:18 char:46
>   + [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$($CerPass){ENTER}")
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception
> ```
>
> [error]Non-Zero exit code: '1' for ComputerName: 'PQAFCTC1'
>
> [error]Atleast one remote job failed. Consult logs for more details. ErrorCodes(s): 'RemoteDeployer_NonZeroExitCode'
>
> [section]Finishing: Run PowerShell on Target Machines

I need it to be automatically send the password to the file when installing. When i run the ps1 file directly on the server it works fine, but I need this script to be part of pipeline task (azure devops pipeline).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you try run this pipeline with self-hosted agent?Will using private agent get the same error?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT when Agent is running "As Service" the pipeline works fine, but not so much when the agent is running "As Interactive Process".

Comment: The sn tool  does not allow passing the password on the command-line or by redirecting stdin.You can refer to this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/671624/a-pipeline-task-to-import-a-pfx-file-into-the-stro.html).